# css: text should be centered but it's not, and if I augment the margin it becomes centered... not logical?

Tags: css

Here's another part of my website, which is incredibly simple:

- I have the body
- I have a div inside the body where I precise (CSS): `text-align:center;`
- I have a `p` with a small text inside.
- if I want to remove the `margin` and `padding`, the first line of the text is not centered anymore (°_°)

I really don't understand that: if there's less margin, there's more space, so the text should stay centered!

Here's the picture of the `div` (with the CSS):

[image: picture of the div (with the CSS)]

Here's the picture of `p` inside the `div`: look closely: the margin is 12px and the text (first line) is not centered.

[image: picture of p inside the div]

And when I **augment** the margin the text becomes eventually centered: look closely: the margin is 13px and the text (first line) is centered!!

[image: when I **augment** the margin the text becomes eventually centered]

Any idea what I should do to have a small `margin-top` and a small `margin-bottom` with the text still properly centered?

If I add `overflow:hidden` to the `.devis-description` class here's what it gives:

[image: add overflow hidden to the class]

Comment: try adding `overflow:hidden` to the `.devis-description` class and see if that helps. It looks like something it running into the text which could be causing your issue. Worth a shot

Comment: Is it possible for you ton include a link to your website ?

Comment: @Greg sorry it's a full dev site, I can't put it online :'(

Comment: @Seth If i do `overflow:hidden` the whole paragraph goes to the left (I'll update my question if it may help to find the answer)

Comment: I think the issue is related to `width:100%` can you set this as a hard value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` and `clear: both;` to both the `devis-description` and the `devis-top`. You can also temporarily add a solid black border to both of them in order to see the edges clearly. My guess is that some element is flowing out of one of them and pushing your text aside.

Comment: Clear: both prevents floated elements on either side of the element it is applied to and pushes it down. Without seeing more of your code, I can't say exactly, but some floated element somewhere was pushing your text around.

Answer (score 0):

try putting a `margin: 0 auto;` to the `<p>`